# Why does the Rinkeby testnet stats page show hashpower when it uses PoA?

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, proof-of-authority

The Rinkeby testnet reportedly runs on the Clique Proof of Authority consensus engine, yet https://www.rinkeby.io/#stats is reporting a hashrate and difficulty. What is the meaning of this?